# ¿Se puede cambiar mariaDB de XAMPP por Mysql?

Tags: base-de-datos, xampp, mariadb

Cuando instale XAMPP me aparecio mariaDB en phpMyAdmin en el apartado de Tipo de servidor[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y cuando intente acceder a cmd para hacer una base de datos en MySQL desde consola me aparecio tambien mariaDB
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hasta la versión 5.6.12<sup>`1`</sup>, XAMPP incluyó MySQL. Después cambió a MariaDB<sup>`2`</sup>.

Particularmente, esta última versión con MySQL contiene:

- Apache 2.4.16
- PHP 5.5.28 / 5.6.12
- MySQL 5.6.26
- phpMyAdmin 4.4.14

---

*Notas*

1. Puede descargarse de [aquí](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/5.6.12/).
2. [New XAMPP with MariaDB](https://www.apachefriends.org/blog/new_xampp_20151019.html)